# My AJAX isn't posting or responding when the user clicks submit

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, real-time

I am trying to have a list of events and on each event have a tick box and a x box, so one for marking the event as complete and the other as marking it as deleted. I want this to happen without refreshing the page and every time I click the button, nothing happens.

I think whats causing the issue is that I could have more than 1 event box, and they aren't unique but i'm unsure how to make sure they are unique so that the right event gets updated in my database. I do have separate files but they just contain my queries for it, the issue i've got is it's not even posting the data. It just does nothing when I click the box.

**HTML/PHP**

```
                <div class="w3-card w3-round w3-white w3-center delete_mem">
              <div class="w3-container">
                <p>Upcoming Event</p>
                <!-- <img src="/w3images/avatar6.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50%"><br> -->
                <span><?= $appRow['customer_appointments_type']; ?></span>
                <p><?= $appRow['customer_appointments_datetime']; ?></p>
                <div class="w3-row w3-opacity">
                  <div class="w3-half">
                    <!-- <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section" title="Complete"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button> -->
                    <a id="<?= $appRow['customer_appointments_id']; ?>" class='w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section btn-good'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="w3-half">
                    <!-- <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-red w3-section" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button> -->
                    <a id="<?= $appRow['customer_appointments_id']; ?>" class='w3-button w3-block w3-red w3-section btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Javascript/AJAX**

```
            //Mark as deleted without refreshing the page
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "scripts/lead/deleteLeadTask.php",
                        data: ({
                            id: id
                        }),
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

        //Mark as complete without refreshing the page
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn-good').click(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to complete this appointment?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "scripts/lead/completeLeadTask.php",
                        data: ({
                            id: id
                        }),
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: How specifically is this failing?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Is the click handler being invoked at all?  Is the `confirm()` invoked?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: fyi, `$(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');` You don't have elements with that class, you only have `delete_mem`

Comment: Anything in your browser's DevTools? Javascript errors? Is the Ajax url triggered? What's its response?

Comment: Nothing is happening, when i got into DevTools nothing is happening, no triggeres, nothing

Comment: @BenSmith: So the click event handlers aren't triggered at all?  That implies they're not being bound in the first place.  In the document ready handler, try doing `console.log($('.btn-danger'))` and see if it finds any elements.  Are these elements being added to the page dynamically perhaps?

Comment: It's really weird, I have another section on the page that is a little JS drop down, so the user can expand for more info with 3 tabs. Originally I added my AJAX/JS inside the same Script tabs as this code and it prevented the drop downs from working. I have since changed it so they are in their own Script tabs and my dropdowns are working again. Would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

First, as you mentioned, you shouldn't have different elements with the same ID. Change your code to something like this

Html

`<button type="button" onClick='delete(<?= $appRow['customer_appointments_id']; ?>)' class='w3-button w3-block w3-red w3-section btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button>`

Then for the Javascript, write the function that will be called when someone clicks the delete button

Javascript

`function delete(id){
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?")) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "scripts/lead/deleteLeadTask.php",
         data: ({
             id: id
         }),
         cache: false,
         success: function(html) {
            $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
         }
     });
  } else {
      return false;}
}`

Comment: After playing around i've managed to get a response, now when I click a button it'll prompt me with 'Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?'. But when I click 'Ok' it'll give me this message in the console 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at bad (lead?cid=1:472)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (lead?cid=1:392)' i've checked the line and on that line it's ' $.ajax({'

Comment: I've used the code you supplied too, so it's the third line down on your AJAX if that helps!

Comment: That error about `$` not being found suggests you haven't actually loaded jQuery beforehand, `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Like @JeremyJones says, it seems you have not loaded JQuery. Make sure you load JQuery before calling that function.